# Why is an image input sending a bad request when a submit input doesn't?

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP with a Spring form tag () on it within a Spring MVC application. I have an input that is type image and I am trying to submit the form to the controller.

The form in JSP:

```
    <form:form action="/spae/welcome" modelAttribute="action" method="post">
        <form:input type="image" src="/spae/resources/images/img.png" path="id"
              name="userAction" value="expand_2" style="width:20px;height:20px;" onclick="increaseJSCounter('1');"/>

    </form:form>
```

However, when I click this input to submit the form, I get an Error 400 bad request, but when I change the input type to "submit" it successfully submits and the application runs correctly.

Does anyone no how to get this image input/submit to work properly?

To help I am adding the code for the controller method below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateService(@RequestParam("userAction") String userAction,
        @ModelAttribute("action") UserInteraction action, ModelMap model) {
        /** set User authority and name here **/
        if(userAction.equals("Search")){
            System.out.println(action.getSearchField());
            System.out.println(action.getSearchInput());
        /** call service parameter update for search here **/
        }else if(userAction.equals("Update")){
            for(int i=0;i<action.getRetroUpdates().length;i++){
                System.out.println(action.getRetroUpdates());
            }
            System.out.println(action.getUpdateStatus());
            /** call service parameter update for UPdating retros here **/
        }else if(userAction.substring(0, 6).equals("expand")){
            spaeUser.setRetroDetailid(Integer.parseInt(userAction.substring(7)));
        }else{
            /** for admin/retro r **/
        }
        model.addAttribute("retroView",getRetroView.getData());
        model.addAttribute("action", new UserInteraction());    
        return "welcome";
     }
```

And the model attributes class:

```
    public class UserInteraction {
        private String id;
        /*other variables not relevent to this issue */            

        public String getId(){
            return this.id;
        }
        public void setId(String id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        /*other appropriate getters and setters for other variables */        }
```

After reviewing somethings I have made this change to the form:

```
    <form:form id="myForm" action="/spae/welcome" modelAttribute="action" method="post">
        <form:checkbox path="id" name="userAction" id="expand_check_${sum.getId()}" value="expand_${sum.getId()}" class="hidden" />
        <image src="/spae/resources/images/expand_grey.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;" onclick="increaseExpandCount('1');$('#expand_check_${sum.getId()}').prop('checked', true);document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"/>
    </form:form>
```

I did this thinking it will behave like another set of inputs and submission I have in the jsp. However, I am still getting a 400 Bad request. Am i heading in the right direction with this idea? Again my goal is to have an image behave like a form submit button.

I think I may have found the solution. I have done this:

```
    <form:form id="myForm" action="/spae/welcome" modelAttribute="action" method="post">
        <form:input path="userAction" name="userAction" type="hidden" />
        <image src="/spae/resources/images/expand_grey.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;" onclick="increaseExpandCount('1');document.getElementById('myForm').actionUser.value='expand_${sum.getId()}';document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"/>
    </form:form>
```

After making this change I am getting errors in the controller so I am assuming that I have succeeded in sending the request. Will let people know if this does work.

---

I managed to figure it out., and will submit this as an answer once I can tonight. I was on the correct path with my most recent post update above. The final product is this:

```
    <form:form id="myForm" action="/spae/welcome" modelAttribute="action" method="post">
        <form:input path="userAction" name="userAction" type="hidden" id="expand_input" value="" />
        <image src="/spae/resources/images/expand_grey.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;" onclick="increaseExpandCount('1');document.getElementById('expand_input').value='expand_${sum.getId()}';document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"/>
    </form:form>
```

This successfully sends the value of the hidden input while using the image as a submit button.

Thank you to all who replied and answered this question; you were a big help.

Comment: You misspelled `src` and are missing the opening `"` for the `src` path.

Comment: The form input should read `<form:input type="image" src="/spae/resources..."`. Not sure if you have that misspelled in your code or here and missing the double quotes, but see if that helps and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I have tried adding an id to the form:form tag and then adding the javascript function document.getElementById(form's id).submit() but I still continue to get the 400 bad request.

Comment: no that was a misspelling when i type it into the site not in my code but thanks for the catch i will fix it.

Comment: Bad request error comes, when you send incorrect data to the controller. Can you give your class of modelAttribute "action"

Comment: what is the data type of "id" in "action" ?

Comment: the id is string but i forgot to add another attribute to the input, the name attribute to pass a parameter to the controller. I will update the question with the code the controller method. The code I have here is using generic names of the variables. The java type for 'id' is String

Comment: No need to specify name attribute, since you are giving path it will automatically converts as name. what you are trying to send to the controller? is it the path of the image ?

Comment: The problem is due to mismatch of datatypes, you are trying to send an image and you keep the datatype as String

Comment: I want to send the value of value to the controller not the value of the image src is there a way to do that without drasticall changing the code? My goal is to have this image in the html that when clicked sends a value ("expand_#") to the controller to be processed by the service.

Comment: Or is there a way to hide the submit button with an image and still submit, i am loking for the simplest solution to display an image in the browser, and have it send the value string to the controller when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send value attribute in image to the controller, then remove path="id" from image, remove name="userAction" give an id to image element as below

```
 <input type="image" src="/spae/resources/images/img.png" id="image"
           value="expand_2" style="width:20px;height:20px;" />
```

and add one hidden input

```
<form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="hiddenId"/>
```

Give an id to your form. Now your forms looks as

```
<form:form action="/spae/welcome" modelAttribute="action" method="post" id="myform" >
    <input type="image" src="/spae/resources/images/img.png" id="image"
           value="expand_2" style="width:20px;height:20px;" />
    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="hiddenId"/>
    <input type="submit"/>

</form:form>
```

and write a onsubmit function for your form

```
$('#myform').sumbit(function(){
   var value = $('#image').val();
   $('#hiddenId').val(value);
   return true;
});
```

Try it it should work now

Comment: unfortunately, according to Spring form the form:input type="image" tag requires a path attribute. Also this is going to give me an image and a submit button i just want to see the image and perform exactly what the submit button does.

Comment: See the updated answer, don't use <form:input type="image" .....> normal <input> tag is enough

Comment: This answer helped a lot and it lead me to my eventual answer. A <form:image.../> submits the coordinates (top,left,bottom,right) of the image, not a specific value associated with the element. So in order to get this to work, you need to have a <form:input type='hidden'.../> that is tied to the form's path variable, and when the image is clicked, it updates this hidden input and then has the form submit.